# Как создать возрастание Шанса на заклинивание?

Tags: c++

Никак не могу создать прогу которая бы создала шанс заклинивание оружии. Например, Начальный Шанс это 0.05% и что бы каждый следующий выстрел увеличил данный шанс на 0.025%.
Если этот оружия заклинит то тогда вернуть начальный Шанс (то есть всё началось с нуля)

PS: если что такое вы должны были увидеть в игре Stalker.

Comment: Ну просто переменная "шанс", которая при каждом успешном выстреле увеличивается. При неудачном - сбрасывается. В чем проблема - совершенно непонятно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Т.е. такая логика?

```
Выстрел() {
   if (randfloat < chance)  {
       заклинило;
       chance = 0.0005;
   } 
    else  {
       стреляем; 
       chance += 0.00025;
       if (chance > 1.0)
           chance = 1.0;
    } 
 }
```

По-хорошему, вместо волшебных чисел нужно ввести константы `CHANCE_MIN` и `CHANCE_STEP` и в коде использовать именно их.